# Swift popToViewController does not working

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I'm new in Swift and iOS dev however I think that I know how to eat it.
I have a problem when trying to use popToViewController. The problem is that I want to "clear" UINavigation stack when pressing the button. 
So I did this like here:

```
navigationController?.popToViewController((navigationController?.viewControllers[0])!, animated: false)
```

I want to have only first ViewController in the stack.
Before I click on the button stack contains

```
([<EmpMan.ViewController: 0x7fd191535ba0>,
 <EmpMan.TableViewController: 0x7fd191564be0>,
 <EmpMan.NewEmployee: 0x7fd1916c0320>])
```

When I click on the button the stack looks:

```
([<EmpMan.ViewController: 0x7fd191535ba0>,
 <EmpMan.TableViewController: 0x7fd191564be0>,
 <EmpMan.NewEmployee: 0x7fd1916c0320>,
 <EmpMan.TableViewController: 0x7fd19171dbf0>])
```

I think after popToViewController the stack should contains only ViewController. Why it does not work?

Comment: How about `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`?

Comment: Did not test, but later in other feature I want to use the same, without going to the ground of the stack, but e.g for the second position in the stack.

Comment: popToRootViewControllerAnimated works fine. But what if I want to reach second position in the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what the button does is a segue, than just do the "Show detail segue and you are done.

Otherwise, make a boolean in the viewController with the button that is set to true when you press the button. Create a secondary segue out of each of the possible segue routes out of the controller. Then if that boolean is set to true, use a "Show Detail Segue" as your next segue instead of a "Show Segue".

Show Detail automatically clears the navigation stack. There are other ways of handling this as well, but I am just throwing you an acceptable answer that works. Read more about segues and custom segues and the navigation stack to get a thourough understanding. It is worth your time if you want to get heavy into iPhone App dev.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. I have just change segue from Push to Show Detail as you advised and now it works as expected.
Thanks!! :)